# Compare multiple input values with stored database

Tags: php

I am building a quiz project. I want to compare the selected options in the form then check it with the correct option in the row values then compare. And count the correct comparisons then echo out. How can I do it?

MY form is below

```
<div class="answer-quiz">
    <form method="post">
    <div>
  <?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM quizzes WHERE quiz_add_id=32";
  $select_question_quiz_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

  if (!$select_question_quiz_query) {
    die(mysqli_error());
  }
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_question_quiz_query)) {     
    $quiz_question = $row['quiz_question'];
    $quiz_option_A = $row['quiz_option_A'];
    $quiz_option_B = $row['quiz_option_B'];
    $quiz_option_C = $row['quiz_option_C'];
    $quiz_option_D = $row['quiz_option_D'];
    $quiz_option_correct = $row['quiz_option_correct'];
       
?>
<div class="quiz-question-div"><?php echo $quiz_question; ?></div>
    <div class="quiz-options">
    <ul class="ul">
    <li>
    <span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="optionA">
    </span>
    <span>
      <?php echo $quiz_option_A; ?>
    </span>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="optionB">
      </span>
      <span>
        <?php echo $quiz_option_B; ?>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="optionC">
      </span>
      <span>
        <?php echo $quiz_option_C; ?>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="optionD">
      </span>
      <span>
        <?php echo $quiz_option_D; ?>
      </span>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>          

    <?php }  ?>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit-quiz" class="btn-primary btn btn-lg final-submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

My PHP isset is below

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit-quiz'])) {
        $box_array = $_POST['box'];

        // selecting the correct option from the db 
        $query = "SELECT quiz_option_correct FROM quizzes WHERE quiz_add_id=32";
        $select_question_quiz_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        $quiz_option_correct=array();

        if (!$select_question_quiz_query) {
            die(mysqli_error($connection));
        }
        for($i=0;$i<5 && ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_question_quiz_query, MYSQLI_BOTH));$i++) {
            $quiz_option_correct[$i] = $row['quiz_option_correct'];       
            $box = $box_array[$i];
            echo $quiz_option_correct[$i];
            echo $box[$i];
        }

    //    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_question_quiz_query, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    //     $quiz_option_correct = $row['quiz_option_correct']; 
    //        
    //            echo $quiz_option_correct;
    //        
    //    }
    }
?>
```

My project view:
[image: My project view]
db:
[image: db]